# calculate the sum of the effective daily average temperatures

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, sum

I'm new to python and I want to calculate the sum of the daily average temperatures on many hours and then append it to the dataframe  e.g :

| date | Temperature |
| --- | --- |
| 2015-04-01 00:00:00 | 3.9 |
| 2015-04-01 01:00:00 | 2.10 |
| 2015-04-01 02:00:00 | 4.8 |
| ⋮ | ⋮ |
| 2015-10-31 23:00:00 | 2.16 |

I'm trying to get this output:

| date | Temperature | averageT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2015-04-01 00:00:00 | 3.9 | 5 |
| 2015-04-01 01:00:00 | 2.10 | 5 |
| 2015-04-01 02:00:00 | 4.8 | 5 |
| ⋮ | ⋮ |  |
| 2015-10-31 23:00:00 | 2.16 | 7 |

Answer (score 0):

```
df['averageT'] = df.resample(rule='D', on='date').transform('mean')
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this as input data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': [pd.Timestamp('2015-04-01 00:00:00'),pd.Timestamp('2015-04-01 01:00:00'),pd.Timestamp('2015-04-01 02:00:00'),pd.Timestamp('2015-10-31 23:00:00')],
    'Temperature': [3.9, 2.1, 4.8, 2.16]
})
```

```
                 date  Temperature
0 2015-04-01 00:00:00         3.90
1 2015-04-01 01:00:00         2.10
2 2015-04-01 02:00:00         4.80
3 2015-10-31 23:00:00         2.16
```

Then use `pd.Grouper` to group the data day by day (if there is no data for a day, the mean will be `NaN`.

```
df['averageT'] = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='1D'))['Temperature'].transform('mean')

print(df)
```

```
                 date  Temperature  averageT
0 2015-04-01 00:00:00         3.90      3.60
1 2015-04-01 01:00:00         2.10      3.60
2 2015-04-01 02:00:00         4.80      3.60
3 2015-10-31 23:00:00         2.16      2.16
```

Comment: it gives NaN as an output

Comment: sorry, my fault. I fixed it now.